# Rails minitest required library leading to uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In running a test, the follwoing error is emerging:

```
CartitemsControllerTest#test_update_q_on_last_item:
ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant Barby::DataMatrix
```

In practice this error does not arise and the desired barcodes are being generated according to design.

While this is running within the CartitemsController, the action calls up a partial that is part of class Cart. Moving the test to CartsControllerTest does not alter the error.

It remains apparent though that the required libraries need to be loaded

```
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'
require 'barby/barcode/data_matrix'
```

How can Minitest be hooked up to the libraries required?

Answer (score 0):

Include the relevant require statements before `class ActiveSupport::TestCase`
in `test/test_helper.rb`